# Why doesn't the notion of a supervector space make sense when the base field is characteristic $2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory

I'm currently reading through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.05142.pdf), and it repeatedly mentions (page 4, middle paragraph)

> The
>   second reason is that over fields of characteristic 2, the ordinary definition of supervector spaces does
>   not make sense as parity has no meaning.

But when I read through the definition of a regular supervector space, for example on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space), I see nothing that doesn't work in characteristic $2$. Can someone explain to me what goes wrong?

Comment: Did you read section $1.5$? There is something which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super vector spaces do not just form a category (which makes sense over any field), they form a [symmetric monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_monoidal_category). Part of this structure is the symmetry isomorphism, which involves the "Koszul sign rule"

$$v \otimes w \mapsto (-1)^{|v| |w|} w \otimes v$$

and which affects, for example, what commutative monoids (super commutative algebras) look like in this category. In characteristic $2$ we have $1 = -1$ so the Koszul sign rule reduces to the ordinary symmetry. You can still write down the definition, it's just less interesting.

Comment: So is a commutative algebra in this category just a regular commutative algebra? Is that the issue? Like, is a supercommutative algebra over a field of characteristic $2$ just a regular commutative algebra?

Comment: Over a field of characteristic $2$ a super commutative algebra is just a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded commutative (in the ordinary sense) algebra.